# OpenSceneGraph - Cloack of Invisibility

Tags: rendering, depth, openscenegraph, depth-buffer, culling

I’m new using OSG and I’m having some issues trying to solve a problem.

I’ve created a scene (a quad and two spheres, with a fixed background) and I’m trying to occlude one of the spheres with a transparent quad. I mean, to make a **"Cloak of Invisibility"** so I can see the background image through it, but not the sphere (or whatever in the projective line) that it’s behind it.

I'm totally stuck as all the tests I've been doing haven't got me even close to what I want. I’d be really grateful if you could help me with this, any idea (or code!) would be more than welcome!! =)

I attach the code of the simple scene that I’m using to make the tests.

```
#include <osg/Geometry>
#include <osg/Geode>
#include <osg/Depth>
#include <osg/Texture2D>
#include <osgDB/ReadFile>
#include <osgViewer/Viewer>
#include <osg/ShapeDrawable>
#include <osg/BlendFunc>
#include <osgGA/TrackBallManipulator>

int main ()
{
osg::ref_ptr<osg::Texture2D> texture = new osg::Texture2D;
osg::ref_ptr<osg::Image> image = osgDB::readImageFile( "C:/OpenSceneGraph-3.4.0/esc.jpg" );
texture->setDataVariance(osg::Object::DYNAMIC);
texture->setResizeNonPowerOfTwoHint(false);
texture->setImage( image.get() );

// Background
osg::ref_ptr<osg::Drawable> quad = osg::createTexturedQuadGeometry(osg::Vec3(),osg::Vec3(1.0f,0.0f,0.0f),osg::Vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));
quad->getOrCreateStateSet()->setTextureAttributeAndModes( 0, texture.get() );

osg::ref_ptr<osg::Geode> geodeBack = new osg::Geode;
geodeBack->addDrawable( quad.get() );

osg::ref_ptr<osg::Camera> camera = new osg::Camera;
camera->setCullingActive( false );
camera->setClearMask( 0 );
camera->setAllowEventFocus( false );
camera->setReferenceFrame( osg::Transform::ABSOLUTE_RF );
camera->setRenderOrder( osg::Camera::POST_RENDER );
camera->setProjectionMatrix( osg::Matrix::ortho2D( 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0) );
camera->addChild( geodeBack.get() );

osg::StateSet* ss = camera->getOrCreateStateSet(); 
ss->setMode(GL_LIGHTING, osg::StateAttribute::OFF);
ss->setMode(GL_DEPTH, osg::StateAttribute::ON);
ss->setAttributeAndModes( new osg::Depth( osg::Depth::LEQUAL,0.99,1.0 ) );


// Quad geometry
osg::ref_ptr<osg::Vec3Array> vertices = new osg::Vec3Array;
vertices->push_back( osg::Vec3(-1.0f, 1.0f,-1.0f) );
vertices->push_back( osg::Vec3( 0.0f, 1.0f,-1.0f) );
vertices->push_back( osg::Vec3( 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f) );
vertices->push_back( osg::Vec3(-1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f) );

osg::ref_ptr<osg::Vec3Array> normals = new osg::Vec3Array;
normals->push_back( osg::Vec3(0.0f,-1.0f, 0.0f) );

osg::ref_ptr<osg::Vec4Array> colors = new osg::Vec4Array;
colors->push_back( osg::Vec4(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f) );

osg::ref_ptr<osg::Geometry> quad2 = new osg::Geometry;
quad2->setVertexArray( vertices.get() );
quad2->setNormalArray( normals.get() );
quad2->setNormalBinding( osg::Geometry::BIND_OVERALL );
quad2->setColorArray( colors.get() );
quad2->setColorBinding( osg::Geometry::BIND_OVERALL );

quad2->addPrimitiveSet( new osg::DrawArrays(GL_QUADS, 0, 4) );

osg::ref_ptr<osg::Geode> geodeTransp = new osg::Geode;
geodeTransp->addDrawable( quad2.get() );


osg::ref_ptr<osg::BlendFunc> blendFunc = new osg::BlendFunc;
blendFunc->setFunction( GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA );
osg::StateSet* stateset = geodeTransp->getOrCreateStateSet();
stateset->setAttributeAndModes( blendFunc ); 

// I'd see both spheres if I uncomment this. Otherwise I'd see the blue osg default background
//stateset->setRenderingHint( osg::StateSet::TRANSPARENT_BIN );

// Sphere 1
osg::ref_ptr<osg::ShapeDrawable> shape1 = new osg::ShapeDrawable;
shape1->setShape( new osg::Sphere(osg::Vec3(-0.3f,0.5f,-0.3f), 0.2f) );
shape1->setColor( osg::Vec4(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f) );

// Sphere 2
osg::ref_ptr<osg::ShapeDrawable> shape2 = new osg::ShapeDrawable;
shape2->setShape( new osg::Sphere(osg::Vec3(-0.7f,1.5f,-0.7f), 0.2f) );
shape2->setColor( osg::Vec4(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f) );

osg::ref_ptr<osg::Geode> geodeFront = new osg::Geode;
geodeFront->addDrawable( shape1.get() );
geodeFront->addDrawable( shape2.get() );

osg::ref_ptr<osg::Group> root = new osg::Group;
root->addChild( camera.get() );
root->addChild( geodeTransp.get() );
root->addChild( geodeFront.get() );

osgViewer::Viewer viewer;
viewer.setSceneData( root.get() );

viewer.setCameraManipulator(new osgGA::TrackballManipulator());
osg::Vec3d eye( -0.5, -3.0, -0.5 );
osg::Vec3d center( -0.5, 0.0, -0.5 );
osg::Vec3d up( 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 );

viewer.getCamera()->setViewMatrixAsLookAt( eye, center, up );

viewer.realize();
while(!viewer.done()) {
    viewer.frame(); 
}
return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance,

Cheers,
Alvaro

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understood what you're after, you should simply render in this specific order:

- the background plane
- the "invisibility" quad
- all the other object (i.e. the two spheres, etc...)

So that everything rendered after the quad, will be masked by it if happens to be behind it. In OSG you can achieve that by assigning explicitly the renderbin to use for the different (groups of) nodes in their stateset:

```
osg::StateSet* stateset = backgroundNode->getOrCreateStateSet();
stateset->setRenderBinDetails(1, "RenderBin");
// and increasing the number for the other nodes...
```

Comment: Hello rickyviking, thanks for the quick response!! 

Really appreciate it

But even setting the rendering order you tell me, it keeps happening to me that

1. If provide the TRANSPARENT_BIN rendering hint: Both spheres are rendered, instead of just the nearest one.

2. If I don't, what I can see is the blue osg default background through the surface of the quad, instead of my fixed background.

-----
(Maybe any kind of rendering a solid quad+updating its stateset to transparent after rendering the sphere(s)? And lately rendering the background..?)

Comment: Sorry @AVGrimaldi, but here there are too many concepts involved that cannot be clarified in a single question. The rendering order I mentioned in my answer should give you the correct result. But you need to know osg better: TRANSPARENT_BIN will sort back to front the objects which is not what you're after, and the stateset cannot be changed while rendering one frame. Check osg archives and examples for the correct usage

Comment: Great, will do for sure! Although I'm still stuck.. as your answer leads to a "quad of background-erasing" too! (Even not using transparent_bin in any case, as you well explained) so there must be something missing, in order to keep here the background custom image intact...